# Why do the eigenvalues of this symmetric matrix come in pairs?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A \in \mathbb R^{m,n}$. I've noticed that the eigenvalues of the symmetric matrix $$S:= \begin{bmatrix}  & A^T \\ A &  \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb R^{m+n,m+n}$$ come in pairs, i.e. the eigenvalues (counting multiplicity) are $$\underbrace{\pm \lambda_1, \ldots, \pm \lambda_k}_{\min\{m,n\} \text{ times}}, \: \: \: \: \: \: \text{ and }  \underbrace{0, \ldots, 0}_{m+n-2\min\{m,n\}  \text{ times}}$$ where some of $\lambda_j$ are possibly zero too (depending on the rank of $A$).

So why do they come in pairs?

Comment: In a generic situation, if $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A^TA$, then $\pm \lambda$ are eigenvalues for $S$ (if $A^TAX=\lambda^2 X$, then $Z=(X,\frac{1}{\lambda}AX)$ satisfies $SZ=\lambda Z$). Gotta be careful with the edge cases though

Comment: Let $v$ be an eigenvalue of $A^TA$ with the eigenvalue $\mu = \lambda^2$. Then $S(\pm\lambda v,Av) = (A^TAv, \pm\lambda Av) = (\mu v, \pm\lambda Av) = ((\pm\lambda)^2v,\pm\lambda Av) = \pm \lambda(\pm\lambda v, Av)$.

Comment: An interesting particular case is when $A$ is symmetric. In this case, we can describe $S$ as the Kronecker product $J \otimes A$, with $J=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and it is known that the spectrum of a Kronecker product is the product of the two spectra here $\{-1,1\}$ and $\{\lambda_1,\cdots \lambda_n\}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$S\begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&B^\mathrm t\\B&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}B^\mathrm tv_2\\Bv_1\end{bmatrix}=\lambda\begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\end{bmatrix}\Leftrightarrow\begin{cases}B^\mathrm tv_2=\lambda v_1\\Bv_1=\lambda v_2\end{cases}$$. $$S\begin{bmatrix}-v_1\\v_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}B^\mathrm tv_2\\-Bv_1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda v_1\\-\lambda v_2\end{bmatrix}=-\lambda\begin{bmatrix}-v_1\\v_2\end{bmatrix}$$.